# Modulo operation with PBC library

Tags: cryptography, modulo

I would like to know how it could be possible to compute a modulo operation over `Zr` elements with [PBC](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/) library ?

The library does not offer a primitive to do it directly.

Answer (score 1):

As this library is based on the GMP library, an **idea** is to use its primitives.

Especially the function `mpz_powm(r, b, e, m)`. The [user's guide](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Exponentiation.html) says is sets *r* = (*b^e*) mod *m*. *IMHO*, if you set the *e* to 1, it *should* produce `r = b mod m`.

You also have converting functions in `PBC` for `GMP` :

1. `element_t` to `mpz_t`

   ```
   void element_to_mpz(mpz_t z, element_t e)
   ```
2. `mpz_t` to `element_t`

   ```
   void element_set_mpz(element_t e, mpz_t z)
   ```

I'm working on trying this, I'll update this answer with a `MWE` as soon as I can.